# Web Api Owin: How to "remap/rename" the fields in the json response created by BaseValidatingContext.SetError

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin

I am implementing an OAuth token based security in my Web API2 server (running under IIS)

I am using various bits of middleware that supply `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` etc that take various arguments derived from  `BaseValidatingContext`

For example, I have the following snippet...

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {                       
        var result = await GetAuthenticateAndGetClaimsAsync("dummy", context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (result.HasError)
        {             
          context.SetError("Error code", "Error description);             
          return;
        }
```

The call to `context.SetError("Error code", "Error description);` will cuase the body of the response to have the following contents..

```
{
   "error": "Error code",
   "error_description": "Error description
}
```

I would like to change the names of these fields to reflect what I use elsewhere in the application for errors, so I can have something like..

```
 {
   "code": "Error code",
   "message": "Error description
}
```

Is this possible, and if so how can I do this?

May be good to be able to set the status code myself too, but that that not that important, it is more the above fields I would like to change.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Hi ..what to remap the object?..the context.SetError ..return somehting?

Comment: Yes I would like the error object returned to have the fields code and message rather than error and error_description

Comment: ok so try to remap it on your custom object ..something like public class MyCusotmError { public string message {get; set;} public string code {get; set;}} and then var error =   context.SetError("Error code", "Error description);         and then var my csutomeror = new MyCusotmError { message = error. error_description , code = error.error}

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try to create your custom error object and then maybe a method (extension method) to map from error of AspNEt to yours ..somehting like:

```
public class MyCustomError{

  public string Code {get; set;}
  public string Message {get; set;}

}
```

then you can create

```
public static class ErrorManager{

   public static ToMyCustomError(this Error err){ //<-- set Here the CORRECT TYPE RETURNING FROM context.SetError
      return new MyCustomError{
        Code = err.error;
        Message=err.error_description;
       }
   }
}
```

and then you can use like this:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {                       
        var result = await GetAuthenticateAndGetClaimsAsync("dummy", context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (result.HasError)
        {             

          return context.SetError("Error code", "Error  description).ToMyCustomError();
        }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that SetError() has no return type (it is void)

Comment: unfortunately no. I did check that [here](https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/Provider/BaseValidatingContext.cs) and as we can see there is no overload.